# methods of calculating the Tau function in number theory (the number of prime divisors of a natural number)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was generating a sequence in code, which I will denote by $SNV(n)$, generated by this rule :

> $SNV(n) = \sum_{x | n + x}^{} 1$ for all x of [1,2,3...] (where p | q means p divides q)

e.g. $SNV(2) = 2, SNV(40) = 8$ etc, but I noticed certain properties of the sequence like the fact that for all primes, p, $SNV(p) = 2$ and $SNV($p^2$) = 3$, and eventually I noticed that SNV(n) = Tau(n) (which I checked on the online sequence encyclopaedia).

basically I was wondering where I could find more detailed proof $SNV(n) = Tau(n)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: We have $x\mid n+x \iff x\mid n$ , so SNV(n) couns the number of divisors of $n$ hence is just tau(n).